# Мультивен - тип авто. Надо кавычить?

Tags: пунктуация

Мультивен - тип авто. Надо кавычить?

Answer (score 3):

**Запись названия зависит от текста.**

**В специальной литературе** это Volkswagen Multivan (Фольксваген Мультивен), в разговорном варианте возможны такие названия: приобрёл подержанный мультивен, ремонт фольксвагена мультивен.

**В художественной литературе** лучше использовать кавычки, так как название марки не такое популярное, как джип. Здесь использование кавычек связано с частотностью употребления слова: известно ли  оно потенциальному читателю или малознакомо.

Answer (score 1):

Кавычить слово *мультивен* не надо, иначе пришлось бы кавычить и слово *джип*, и слово *спорткар* и т.д.